# Apache Cordova File API via Windows Phone

Tags: apache, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have tried to use Apache Cordova File Plugin [documentation](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_file_file.md.html) 
Here is my code. It just basically goes through all folders into file system.

```
function log(text) {
        var element = document.createElement('div');
        element.innerHTML = text;

        document.getElementById("log").appendChild(element);
    }


    function onSuccess(fileSystem) {

        function printEntries(entries) {
            log("Enter printEntries function");

            var i;
            log("Number of entries" + entries.length);
            for (i = 0; i < entries.length; i++) {
                log("Interation number " + i);
                if (entries[i].isFile) {
                    log(entries[i].name);
                } else {
                    log("Moving into subdirectory name: " + entries[i].name);
                    entries[i].createReader().readEntries(printEntries, fail);
                }
            }
        }

        function fail(error) {
            log("Failed to list directory contents: " + error.code);
        }

        // Get a directory reader
        var directoryReader = fileSystem.root.createReader();

        // Get a list of all the entries in the directory
        directoryReader.readEntries(printEntries, fail);
    }

    // request the persistent file system
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, null);
```

When I deploy my application to the my Lumia I have only this directories:
 /
  -Shared 
     ---Media 
     ---ShellContent 
     ---Transfers 
  -debugOutput.txt 
  -DeviceID.txt

It seams that I have no access to files, that stored on my phone (images, videos).

So, my question is: Is it possible to get files from phone file system and sd card?

Comment: Outside of PhoneGap/Cordova, you need to use special APIs to access Media and SD cards on Windows Phone ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx ) however I don't know how to access them via Cordova just yet. I'll reply with an answer when/if I find out, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, it seems, that I have my local html5 file storage, and probably I am just looking in the wrong direction. =)

Comment: Unfortunately, Reading files under SD card is not supported yet by Apache Cordova for Windows Phone 8. Hopefully, it will be supported soon.

Comment: Someone is able to solve it? I need to read SD card files from a winphone 8.1