# Apache Cordova Can't Read a File from Root Directory

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to read a file using cordova with this code. But I am not able to see alert inside `fileSystem.root.getFile` function.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
           function (fileSystem) { 
               alert("root name=" + fileSystem.root.name); //alert working
              //after this not working 
               var path = "index.html";
               fileSystem.root.getFile(path, null, function (fileEntry) {
                   alert('file entry');

                   fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);

               }, fail);
           }, fail);

       function fail(error) {
           alert("File System Error:" + error.code);
       }
```

I get error code `1`. I am using visual studio cordova hybrid app plugin (2013).

## Update Solved:

I solved the problem by going to my bin -> windows phone directory. And then i renamed the .xap file to .zip to extract the content. I found there that my files are correctly deployed along with cordova plugins. But my files were inside `www` directory. So i sepcified the path and it works now;

```
var path = "www/index.html";
```

But i am really wondering why cordova documentation didn't mention this but anyway i solved it now;

Comment: Hi, can you add the platform where you got this error code?

Comment: @NicolasR in windows phone

Comment: Windows Phone 8? 8.1?

Comment: windows phone 8 because by default, cordova plugin for visual studio start wp 8 simulator but i deploy to wp8.1 still the same error

Comment: Maybe you can try to list the directories in your storage to ensure that you really are where you think you are, like the OP of this question did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600166/apache-cordova-file-api-via-windows-phone Thats sounds basic, but with all the isolatedStorage part in WP, maybe you should check

Comment: @NicolasR and it works in Cordova Ripple broswer test plugin.So i guess this could be the problem

Comment: What is working? Your question code? I think I found something interesting in the code of the plugin, but cannot test right now.
In the C# code, it is checking `if (filePath.IndexOf("www") == 0)` and if not, return the error you got...

Comment: @NicolasR yes my code works on browser but not in simulator

Comment: Can you check in the emulator the method from the question I provided? And also, are you using PhoneGap 3.5?

Comment: That was not working for me in Ripple or any other emulator in VS2015 or in a real device (Windows Phone or Surface Pro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just posted an answer to a similar question with working code example here:
[Loading an array stored in a text file in phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25382572/loading-an-array-stored-in-a-text-file-in-phonegap)

I think Abhishek's answer is quite helpful by the way.

Comment: I'm sorry but... how does your answer helps here?

Comment: @NicolasR Original poster's code is not working, it looks like file api use is problematic. I gave a working (tested) example code that does the same thing in a slightly different way, so I suppose it will help. As an alternative, I pointed out that Abhishek's answer is also good, OP had a different comment under it (saying it's not working) when I posted my response by the way..

Comment: @mentat, you link was helpful as now it works when i point the path to `var path = "www/index.html";`. So, i will make this as your credit.

Answer (score 2):

Error is reported because `fileSystem.root.getFile` is not able to find index.html at location pointed by LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT. You can log `fileSystem.root.fullPath` to find the path where `fileSystem.root.getFile()` is looking into in your device or system.

Your apps files like index.html are not stored or dropped at LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT unless it is explicitly copied there. You can find more detail on where LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT points in SO question [Where does LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT point to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399465/where-does-localfilesystem-persistent-point-to)

Comment: the full path returned `/` and my index.html is in my root directory also

Comment: i extracted the .xap file, my files are there inside `www` folder

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var path = "./index.html";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate the filesystem.root.name and your current path to create an absoulte path to the location of the file relative to the phone file system, then pass that into the path parameter of fileSystem.root.getFile. Right now your path is incomplete. Hope it helps!!